# Zabbix external check and dashboard logging

Tags: zabbix

I am using zabbix 3.4.10. I have created and configured an external check that will basically parse an XML file and return errors if any. On the display side, there is a dashboard's plain text widget that displays the external check item output. The widget will refresh data every 10 seconds. My question is the following: Is there a way to tell Zabbix that there is nothing new? my widget keeps displaying the last error every 10 seconds and if i try to return some empty string, the widget displays it. If i try to return an exit code different of 0, it still displays empty string. Is there way to tell zabbix that there is "no value"?

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer to my question. I was able to find a solution after some thorough search and testing that i would like to share. So basically here is how you tell Zabbix that the external script has "no value". The underlying need was to avoid having Zabbix repeating data in the dashboards or showing empty data when no changes in the external scripts output has been made available.

So to make things short: you have to make your external script unsupported then Zabbix will try to refresh every unsupported item periodically based on a timeout. To make your script unsupported, you can simply make it "wait" until the configured Zabbix timeout is reached. Here are the details about the Zabbix timeout:

1. In the zabbix_server.conf (located in /etc/zabbix) you have to uncomment the Timeout parameter. This parameter represents the timeout after which Zabbix considers the currently executing script as being unsupported. The default is to have a timeout of 3 seconds so you can set the timeout in seconds you want. If a script becomes unsupported, Zabbix will just not update the dashboards using it.
2. Then you can setup Zabbix to refresh unsupported scripts after a certain interval of time so that it can check if further data is available. To do so, you go there:

Zabbix => administration => Other (in the dropdown list) => Refresh Unsupported items.

This interval is in seconds. In my case i have put 10 seconds. So that every 10 seconds Zabbix will re-check by external script.

If there are new data available, the script will not wait to timeout so that it becomes unsupported. It will provide to Zabbix the new data which will be displayed in the dashboard. On the next script execution, if there are no new data, the script will wait until timeout which causes Zabbix to unsupport the script and not update the dashboards. Then, Zabbix will refresh the unsupported items as per the above configuration.